# Convergence of operators: question

Tags: operator-theory

Let $T: X \to X$ be a bounded linear operator on a Banach space $X$, and let $B(0,1) = \{x\in X: \|x\| \le 1 \}$.

I would like to know if the following two conditions are equivalent or not.

(1) $\exists 
~r>0$ such that for any sequence $(x_n)$ in $B(0,1)$,
\begin{align}
   &-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}T^k(x_k)~\mbox{converges to a point in}~ X ~\mbox{and} \\
   &-\|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}T^k(x_k)\| \le r\sup\limits_{k \ge 0}\|x_k\|
\end{align}

(2) $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\|T^k\| < \infty$, i.e., $\sigma(T) < 1$.

I know that (2) implies (1). However, I do not know (1) implies (2) or not.
It would be highly appreciated if you give me an answer.
Thank you in advance.